# SQL - How do I populate the age column if only the year of birth was given?

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

The data only has the year of birth column, labeled `year_birth`.

I added an age column but now I would like to add values to this column to show the age by subtracting the current year by the values in the `year_birth` column.

"year_birth"    "age"
1970
1961
1958
1967
1989
1958
1954
1967
1954
1954

this query returned a syntax error

```sql
-- Update Age column

update marketing_data
set age = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),year_birth)), '%Y') 
 + 0
```

```
ERROR:  function datediff(timestamp with time zone, integer) does not exist
LINE 4: set age = DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),year_birth)),...
                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 

SQL state: 42883
Character: 77
```

Answer (score 4):

Cast your year_birth as int if not already int. Use `extract(year...`.

---

```
update my_data 
set age = extract(year from now()) - year_birth::int;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

By error we can understand you are not using MS SQL-Server but rather PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL does not have function named datediff.

You can get the age from year_birth column like below,

```
UPDATE marketing_data
SET age = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(DATE(year_birth::text || '-01-01')));
```

This will update the age column with age calculated from year_birth values.